# Angularjs directive to grab $scope value which is asynchronus

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angularjs. I want to take my custom directive ' attributes and make http call and generate graph using the response.

```
<lineGraph query="select * from load.webserver[0-9]"></lineGraph>  <!-- query is sent over http to db -->
```

My angularjs code goes like this,

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

//Factory to get data from influxDB over http
app.factory('influxFactory', ['$q', function($q) { 
    .... code for querying db using http
})

//
app.controller('mycontroller', [ '$scope', 'influxFactory', function($scope, influxFactory){ 
    scope.constructGraphData = function(query){
        influxFactory.getDataFromDBOverHTTP().then(function(data){
            ... graph data is constructed here
            $scope.graphdata = constructed_data   // graph data to be plotted is stored and need to be given to drawFlotChart
        })
    }
})

app.directive('lineGraph', function () { 

    function drawFlotChart(graphdata){
        ... flot code to draw the graph
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/linegraph.html',
        link: function(scope, elt, attr){
            // Take value of "query" in <myLineDirective query="load.we... 
            scope.constructGraphData(attr.query)
            /*** How do I capture the $scope.graphdata here ... its "undefined" since http response takes time. Need help.  ***/
        }
})
```

I can't use $watch('graphdata', function()) since 'graphdata' gets modified multiple times while getting constructed and hence there function() gets executed multiple times
I tried with having "scope: {" but no luck. 
    Can somebody help on this ?

Comment: You could do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/qf79h7f2/1/. Note : I use $timeout to replace $http but it should work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$q` in your controller's `constructGraphData` function. Create a deferred object at the beginning of the function, return its promise and resolve with `constructed_data` when it's ready. Then, in your directive, call `scope.constructGraphData(attr.query).then(...)` to use the `graphdata`.